# Reading a file and parsing the data

Tags: python-3.5

I'm reading a file and printing only the lines which have "load" in the line and that's working but i want the data to be More Distinct or clear as the output data is `[soi-aahh] out:  16:45:50 up 436 days,  2:06,  5 users,  load average: 0.08, 0.02, 0.00` where hostname is enclosed within brackets following `out` which i want to remove and want the data to be looks into two column format or at least remove them :

```
$ cat logs.py
#!/python/v3.6.1/bin/python3
with open("file_1") as f:
    data = f.read()
    for line in data.splitlines():
        if "load" in line:
            print(line)
            print("")
```

File contents

```
$ cat file_1
[soi-aahh] sudo: uptime
[soi-aahh] out: sudo password:
[soi-aahh] out:  16:45:50 up 436 days,  2:06,  5 users,  load average: 0.08, 0.02, 0.00
[soi-aahh] out:

[soi-aabk] sudo: uptime
[soi-aabk] out: sudo password:
[soi-aabk] out:  16:45:50 up 586 days, 23:08,  7 users,  load average: 1.01, 1.03, 1.00
[soi-aabk] out:

[soi-abrrj] sudo: uptime
[soi-abrrj] out: sudo password:
[soi-abrrj] out:  16:45:50 up 219 days,  6:31,  4 users,  load average: 0.00, 0.00, 0.00
[soi-abrrj] out:

[soi-ritsh] sudo: uptime
[soi-ritsh] out: sudo password:
[soi-ritsh] out:  16:45:50 up 586 days, 23:13, 15 users,  load average: 5.01, 5.02, 5.04
    [soi-ritsh] out:
```

Script output:

```
$ ./logs.py
[soi-aahh] out:  16:45:50 up 436 days,  2:06,  5 users,  load average: 0.08, 0.02, 0.00

[soi-aabk] out:  16:45:50 up 586 days, 23:08,  7 users,  load average: 1.01, 1.03, 1.00

[soi-abrrj] out:  16:45:50 up 219 days,  6:31,  4 users,  load average: 0.00, 0.00, 0.00

[soi-ritsh] out:  16:45:50 up 586 days, 23:13, 15 users,  load average: 5.01, 5.02, 5.04
```

Desired:

```
Hostname        Uptime
soi-aahh        16:45:50 up 436 days
```

OR at least below:

**soi-aahh:** `16:45:50 up 436 days,  2:06,  5 users,  load average: 0.08, 0.02, 0.00`

Please suggest if there is better way to read the file and do this.

Comment: Just a question, why use `f.read()` instead of `f.readlines()`?

Comment: @Swift,  there is no special case, however the method splitlines() returns a list with all the lines in string, optionally including the line breaks. Whereas  readlines() reads until EOF using readline() and returns a list containing the lines.

Comment: What attempt have you made at parsing the lines?  Inside the loop where you have `line`, how are you trying to pick out the specific parts you need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to trim the line:

```
with open("file_1") as f:
    data = f.read()
    print('Hostname \t Uptime')
    for line in data.splitlines():
        if "load" in line:
            print(line.replace('] out: ', '\t').strip('['))
            print("")
```

Comment: Ai Da,  what is your answer here ?